# Terrain Accessibility map using GIS (ArcGIS or QGIS)

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, dem, terrain

I need to make an accessibility map showing the walking distance based on the terrain and availability of road networks, could anyone point me in the right direction where i could learn to do so.
Basically i need to create something like this:

[image: Map]
[image: Legend]

Comment: How does that work? What are the the axes (X and Y)? How does it deal with uphill vs downhill?

Answer (score 2):

In ArcGIS, you could start with the [path distance](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Path_Distance/009z0000001q000000/) tools if you have the spatial analyst extension. The idea is to create a cost raster that reflect the difficulty to go accross a pixel (a good start is to use the time it would take you). For instance, you walk 2 times faster on a trail than out of trail. With path distance, you can also add additional horizontal and vertical factors. This is very useful in hilly terrains because moving up is not the same as moving down.

With QGIS, you can use [r.walk](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.walk.html) (from GRASS). It is about the same. However, those algorithms need some tuning. And I can't tell which one is the best. This [paper](http://www.academia.edu/398732/Cost_Distance_Analysis_in_an_Alpine_Environment_Comparison_of_Different_Cost_Surface_Modules) was also not sure about it.

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS, there is also (in addition to *r.walk* which @radouxju has mentioned) the **Walking time** plugin which you can download (*Plugins* > *Manage and Install Plugins...*). This uses the [**Tobler's hiking function**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobler%27s_hiking_function) which estimates the travel time based on data from your line layer in relation with the elevation values of the raster layer:

[image: Walking time plugin]

Comment: What a fascinating tool. I had no idea it was there. I'm going to have to look into the algorithm a little more closely.

Comment: @WhiteboxDev, I find it fun to see plugins which are quite specialised. I just have to remember to disable half of them (I've downloaded more than 60) as QGIS tends to grind to a halt when it starts up!